# Bigger file uploads from Chrome browser hang the mod_wsgi

Tags: apache-2.4, django, mod-wsgi

Recently we upgraded mod_wsgi to v 4.5.15. When trying to upload a 700KB or bigger file to a Django project from Chrome, the Django website crashes. The same file upload from Firefox works fluently.

What I found in documentation, that there are more options to configure for mod_wsgi than in previous versions. The complete list of settings is located in [the documentation of WSGIDaemonProcess](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html).

Currently I have only `python-path` defined in the options. If the upload issue is related to the configuration at all, which settings should I try to tackle?

Side question: what could be the difference in Chrome and Firefox that deals differently with file uploads.

Comment: Sadly I think this question will be more suited on Chrome forum in my own opinion, as it seem a product limitation/bug

Comment: I have just reported the issue to Chrome too. Let's see if they can help me to solve this issue. Otherwise, maybe there will be some devops here who knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be a conflict between `mod_wsgi` and `mod_http2` in Apache configuration. There is a reported [similar bug about that](https://github.com/icing/mod_h2/issues/110).

Disabling `mod_http2` fixes the issue. Maybe upgrading `mod_http2` to the latest version will do the same.